# Combining/adding vectors from different word2vec models

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, training-data, corpus

I am using gensim to create Word2Vec models trained on large text corpora. I have some models based on StackExchange data dumps. I also have a model trained on a corpus derived from English Wikipedia.

Assume that a vocabulary term is in both models, and that the models were created with the same parameters to Word2Vec. Is there any way to combine or add the vectors from the two separate models to create a single new model that has the same word vectors that would have resulted if I had combined both corpora initially and trained on this data?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to be able to generate a model with a specific corpus, and then if I process a new corpus later, I want to be able to add this information to an existing model rather than having to combine corpora and retrain everything from scratch (i.e. I want to avoid reprocessing every corpus each time I want to add information to the model).

Are there builtin functions in gensim or elsewhere that will allow me to combine models like this, adding information to existing models instead of retraining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, only word vectors that were trained together are meaningfully comparable. (It's the interleaved tug-of-war during training that moves them to relative orientations that are meaningful, and there's enough randomness in the process that even models trained on the same corpus will vary in where they place individual words.)

Using words from both corpuses as guideposts, it is possible to learn a transformation from one space A to the other B, that tries to move those known-shared-words to their corresponding positions in the other space. Then, applying that same transformation to the words in A that *aren't* in B, you can find B coordinates for those words, making them comparable to other native-B words.

This technique has been used with some success in word2vec-driven language translation (where the guidepost pairs are known translations), or as a means of growing a limited word-vector set with word-vectors from elsewhere. Whether it'd work well enough for your purposes, I don't know. I imagine it could go astray especially where the two training corpuses use shared tokens in wildly different senses.

There's a class, `TranslationMatrix`, that may be able to do this for you in the `gensim` library. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/translation_matrix.html

There's a demo notebook of its use at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/translation_matrix.ipynb

(Whenever practical, doing a full training on a mixed-together corpus, with all word examples, is likely to do better.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Are you aware of any algorithms besides word2vec that do what I described? I really want to avoid having to do retraining on full mixed corpus each time I encounter new data (I'm dealing with 100GB+ of data & it's expensive). I need to build an initial model, and then "add information" to it incrementally, as my web crawler encounters new text. Similar to how a Bayesian spam filter is trained on an initial corpus / training set, and improves over time as user tags spam (without having to retrain with entire corpus for each new piece of data) ...

Comment: I'm writing a web crawler/index that will be searching for pages related to the query terms, and archiving/indexing relevant pages locally. I wanted to use word2vec for text/document "similarity" and "relevance" scoring, to rank results in information retrieval, and to prioritize links in URL frontier. I need some way of improving results over time as more pages are crawled/indexed though. Is word2vec the wrong tool for this?

Comment: I strongly suspect even the giant crawling/indexing projects occasionally do a big batch re-process of all data. Gensim's `Word2Vec` has a feature for incrementally updating the vocabulary (`.build_vocab(newcorpus, update=True)`), *but* it introduces lots of murky issues of how to balance the influence of newer examples versus old. (For example you're only training on newer examples, words being re-tuned by those examples – new or old – can drift out of alignment with words only seen by the model long ago.)

Comment: Word2vec is great for fuzzy search, but not truly an 'online' algorithm, because balance among all word examples requires equal co-training. Are you sure, though, that after a little while there will be that many new words or changing senses? If there are, estimating their positions in the older model might work (by training them up with a mix of content, then mapping them back a la `TranslationMatrix` as you've considered). But also an occasional big background reindex to create a new baseline may be practical as well, unless you need lag from discovery-to-word2vec-enhanced search to be tiny.

Comment: "Are you sure, though, that after a little while there will be that many new words or changing senses?"

My hope is that there will be, yes. I'm writing an application that allows the user to enter a set of queries and optional seed URLs, and then automatically crawls the web building a personalized search engine for the query topics. I want the crawler learn over time (with the help of manual training) which sites/results the user prefers, and common features of the text on those sites, and uses this information to update the word embeddings to fit this desired content more closely.

Comment: I'm using a huge corpus (English Wikipedia + StackExchange dumps) to create the initial embeddings, which takes >20 hours to process, so period reprocessing of the entire dataset really isn't an option. But even very large corpora have certain types of linguistic "bias" embedded in them. So I'd like the crawler to add information to these embeddings from text that the user has marked "relevant", so that over time the embeddings more closely match the users desired content. I agree that the problem of how to "weight" the new information will be challenging, though.

Comment: Fair enough, and if you're constantly discovering new words & shifting senses, then yes, somehow integrating them with your 'starter set' may be necessary. But be open to the idea you might not need to start with "100GB" of text (especially generic or only-somewhat-domain-overlapping text). You might just want to stick with a more focused (and thus quickly batchable-from-zero) corpus from your exact focused crawls/domains.

Comment: If you really do need to work with giant text, be sure to check out: (1) latest gensim releases with a `corpus_file` alternate corpus format to achieve higher effective training parallelism with >8 cores; (2) more aggressive `sample` settings (`1e-06` or lower); (3) other more-extreme parameters – very small `negative` and `window` values speed training far more than they hurt quality, if at all, when data is plentiful, & fewer epochs over a varied/shuffled giant dataset can be as good as more epochs over a smaller one. (I think the `GoogleNews` vectors used just 3 epochs on a giant dataset.)

Comment: "You might just want to stick with a more focused (and thus quickly batchable-from-zero) corpus" ... hmmm that's an interesting idea I hadn't considered. Maybe what I'll do is start with the large corpora, and take a random sampling of sentences for each vocabulary term - the minimum size that provides desired level of initial accuracy. This would shrink corpus size significantly while still giving reasonably accurate embeddings, & then I could retrain reasonably fast as new (manually tagged) text is added ... Definitely not ideal, but better than retraining on full set at least. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, big corpora are great, but if word usage there is different/more-diffuse, it could be a mixed-bag. Having your own "slim-to-relevance" process could work, but note that `sample` also does that - skipping more and more highly-frequent words as you make it more aggressive. That also often delivers an incremental indirect benefit by de facto shrinking windows around rarer words. So if your corpus IO is fast, and you're reading from pre-tokenized text (as with `corpus_file`), `sample` may outdo any bespoke corpus-slimming with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid training a new model on large mixed corpora with translations, I'd recommend checking out my new Python package (`transvec`) that allows you to convert word embeddings between pre-trained word2vec models. All you need to do is provide a representative set of individual words in the target language along with their translations in the source language as training data, which is much more manageable (I just took a few thousand words and threw them into Google translate for some pretty good results).

It works in a similar way to the `TranslationMatrix` mentioned in the other answer in that it works on pre-trained word2vec models, but as well as providing you with translations it can also provide you with the translated word vectors, allowing you to do things like nearest neighbour clustering on mixed-language corpora.

It also supports using regularisation in the training phase to help improve translations when your training data is limited.

Here's a small example:

```
import gensim.downloader
from transvec.transformers import TranslationWordVectorizer

# Pretrained models in two different languages.
ru_model = gensim.downloader.load("word2vec-ruscorpora-300")
en_model = gensim.downloader.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-300")

# Training data: pairs of English words with their Russian translations.
# The more you can provide, the better.
train = [
    ("king", "царь_NOUN"), ("tsar", "царь_NOUN"),
    ("man", "мужчина_NOUN"), ("woman", "женщина_NOUN")
]

bilingual_model = TranslationWordVectorizer(en_model, ru_model).fit(train)

# Find words with similar meanings across both languages.
bilingual_model.similar_by_word("царица_NOUN", 1) # "queen"
# [('king', 0.7763221263885498)]
```

Installation guidance and more details can be found on PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/transvec/.