# How to add words and vectors manually to Word2vec gensim?

Tags: gensim, word2vec

Let's say, **word2vec.model** is my trained word2vec model. When a out-of-vocabulary word (**oov_word**) occurs, I compute a vector **vec** using *compute_vec(oov_word)* method. Now, I want to add/append **oov_word** and its corresponding vector **vec** to my already trained model **word2vec.model**.

I have already checked the below links. But they do not answer my question.

[Combining/adding vectors from different word2vec models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243797/combining-adding-vectors-from-different-word2vec-models)

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49431/how-to-train-an-existing-word2vec-gensim-model-on-new-words

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.BaseKeyedVectors.add

Comment: Just curious, what method of `compute_vec()` for an OOV word are you using?

Comment: By using the context of the out-of-vocabulary word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors
vector_length = 100
kv = WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors(vector_length)

# wordList - list of words
# vectorList - list of the vector corresponding to the words

kv.add(wordList, vectorList)

kv.most_similar(word1) # gives the list of words similar to word1
```

Answer (score 0):

for version 4.0:

```
w2v_model.wv.add_vectors(keys, vectors)
```

Check the [doc](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.add_vectors)

Comment: Adding such extra words to the set of word-vectors inside a full `Word2Vec` model may break the overall model - it's not been designed to handle such arbitrary, out-of-band changes to tis internal `KeyedVectors`. (If you were simply removing the vectors from the model, then adding more, that'd work within limits - but in such a case, you'd want to pull `w2v_model.wv` out to elsewhere, and use it just as a fixed set of vectors.